# RTSP Camera capture C#

Tags: камера, rtsp

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема - Я подключаюсь к камере по RTSP протоколу, но на картинке снизу происходит что то непонятное, на скрине ниже это видно.

Использую: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/885869/Stream-Player-control

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы вначале попробовал к камере подключиться напрямую (через ffmpeg или vlc) и посмотрел картинку.

Comment: Подключался через iVMS 4200, там всё нормально.
Может быть какая то другая есть библиотека для подключения? Кроме Ozeki - Onif.

Comment: данная либа использует ffmpeg. Именно поэтому я и и рекомендую подключиться именно им. Если бага будет повторятся - тогда это проблема ffmpeg и Вам нужно будет искать другую либу. Если же нет - тогда багу у себя.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста ссылку на ffmpeg, в гугле есть какие то, но их там целых 3, и непонятно какая именно.

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие то нормальные документации или примеры? Я что то нашел но работает через заднее место.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49838/discussion-between-user199587-and-kovadim).